# Why doesn't a electron stops to orbit the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrons

We always learned in the high school that electrons always orbit the nucleus (I read about, and it seems that this theory is obsolete: electrons doesn't orbit the nucleus), but I am asking my self now:

How does the electron not stops?

Where does the energy to orbit comes from?

Comment: Sorry, I flagged by myself as Duplicated, now I found the answer :)

Comment: The classical model is similar to planets orbiting a star in Newtonian mechanics. The planets continue orbiting because there is no friction to slow them down, so energy is conserved. Similarly in the planetary model of electron shells (which as you have observed is obsolete) there is nothing to slow down/remove energy from the electrons so they remain in their orbits.

Comment: @IanF1 Unlike planets electrons radiate energy very intensely when accelerating. It was estimated that they would fall into the nuclei and atoms would collapse in $10^{-12}$ seconds. Bohr's "explanation" for why this doesn't happen was that electrons just don't radiate when they are in some specific orbits, just cause. But it worked http://physics.weber.edu/carroll/honors/failures.htm